# Getting all location coordinates of a MKCircleView radius on a MapView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a `MapView` where I draw circle overlays with `MKCircleView` when the user taps the map which works fine but now I need to get all the location coordinates (lat/long) of the radius to store for later use to repopulate the map overlays. How can I get all the locations on the radius so I can show the circle again?

storing just the center point and the radius is not an option because I have to sync these points to a server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the center point and the radius. There are an infinite number of points within and on the boundary of any circle. If you need to draw a circle using data on the server, use the center and radius and whatever circle/ellipse function your drawing library has, or, if need be, use the center and radius and basic trigonometry to generate points on the circle to draw a polygon with. Or if you’re just feeding the data back down to your app, create your MKCircle objects with the class’s `+circleWithCenterCoordinate:radius:` method.

Comment: I am using `circleWithCenterCoordinate:radius:` to show the circle on the map. 

basically the algorithm goes user taps once to indicate the center of the circle then the user taps again away from the center to get the radius then it gets plotted.

sounds like the trig option is going to be my only solution though